# Run specific subs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba button. If I click on it, I'd like VBA to ask me which sub or subs I want to run from the list below.

The VBA button is assigned to the runAllMacros macro, and "Output" etc. are other macros.

```
Public Sub runAllMacros()

Output
Input
General
Bank

End Sub
```

Is this possible and if so how can I implement this in Excel VBA.

Answer (score 0):

An option I can think of is the following - make a form, that comes with checkboxes for Output, Input, General, Bank:

[image]

Then write your code like this:

```
If Form1.Output then
   Output
End if

If Form1.Input then
   Output
End if
```

Comment: I am very new to VBA and hence, this might be a silly question. What do you exactly mean with "make a form, that comes with checkboxes for Output, Input, General, Bank?"

Comment: @Strawhat - it means that in stead of creating a module in VBA you create a form. There you can add buttons and checkboxes. See the updated answer w/ a screenshot.

Comment: Should I write this code in a Module or in the UserForm itself?